# Is there a solution to SUM multiple values from one column into one other column with condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm stuck with a 'SUM' function in Oracle SQL

Here the part of the query I use to calculate the total time in second for all line 'APLFTSK_CODE' named ACC. The name of the column for the results is TIME_TOTAL_ACC

```
SUM (
    CASE
    WHEN
    APLFTSK.APLFTSK_CODE = 'AAC'
    AND APLCALL.APLCALL_NUM = APLTSK.APLTSK_APLCALL
    THEN
    ROUND((APLTSK.APLTSK_FEND - APLTSK.APLTSK_FBEGIN)* (24 * 60)*60) 
    END
    )
```

Here the result I get when I try to 'SUM'

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtFn3.jpg)**

I only got the single result of the line not the sum of all lines meeting the condition. I want the same result '2403' for all line meeting the condition.

I tried a 'group by' on a sub select inside the case but got a "single-row subquery returns more than one row" as result

```
SUM (
    CASE
    WHEN
    APLFTSK.APLFTSK_CODE = 'AAC'
    AND APLCALL.APLCALL_NUM = APLTSK.APLTSK_APLCALL
    THEN
          (
          SELECT 
          ROUND((APLTSK.APLTSK_FEND - APLTSK.APLTSK_FBEGIN)* (24 * 60)*60)  
          FROM APLTSK, APLFTSK 
          GROUP BY APLTSK.APLTSK_NUM,APLFTSK.APLFTSK_CODE
          )
   END
   )
```

I don't know how to deal with that function in that case. I read several examples on how to use 'SUM' function in Oracle but I don't know how to apply it to my case. Most part of the time the 'SUM' is about getting the result of different columns in the same line.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please show your current result as text rather than as an image, and also show the output you are trying to get, along with matching sample data and your full query.

Comment: The `sum` function is an aggregate function -- it returns one value for all the rows that are grouped.  You want a single row or an analytic function; once you provide the info Alex requested, we can probably point you to the appropriate type of function. Single-row functions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#SQLRF51178 Aggregate functions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035 Analytic functions (these are pretty complex...): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the analytic version of `sum()`, something like:

```
CASE WHEN APLFTSK.APLFTSK_CODE = 'AAC' AND APLCALL.APLCALL_NUM = APLTSK.APLTSK_APLCALL
     THEN SUM(ROUND((APLTSK.APLTSK_FEND - APLTSK.APLTSK_FBEGIN) * 24*60*60))
          OVER (PARTITION BY APLFTSK.APLFTSK_CODE)
     ELSE 0
END
```

though it's unclear how any grouping you might have in place could affect the outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex ! That's exactly what I was looking for. It's the first time I use the analytic version of SUM. That's powerfull. I use a lot of grouping in my request to avoid multiple results for the same row so the analytic function is working like a charm.